# Javascript/CSS: donation progress bar with intervals which shows a set value/amount

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar

I am a newbie in Javascript. I have created a 'donation progress bar' with intervals. The bar is activated by a button and it stops at the end of it; But I would like that, once activated, the bar stops to a specific amount which I set (for example 20.000$), and at that point shows this amount in the middle of the bar itself. I have seen one of this kind in wikipedia.
Which is the function I must use to do this? I can not find..
Thanks in advance!

```js
function move() {
  let elem = document.getElementById("progress-bar");
  let stepValue = 0;
  let id = setInterval(frame, 50);

  function frame() {
    if (stepValue >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      elem.style.width = stepValue + 1 + "%";
      elem.innerHTML = stepValue + 1 + "%";
      stepValue = stepValue + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  max-width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
}

.progress-goals {
  margin: 20px auto 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.progress-goals h3 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.progress-goals:last-child {
  flex: 1;
}

.progress-bg {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0px auto 0px;
  height: 78px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #ccc;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #ccc;
}

.goal-bar {
  background-color: rgb(58, 58, 58);
  width: 5px;
  height: 78px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.progress-bar {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  background: linear-gradient( to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 18%, rgba(28, 53, 120, 0.8), rgba(220, 24, 27, 0.8));
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  transition: all 700ms ease;
}

.progress-btn-container {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 50px;
}

.progress-btn {
  /* display: block; */
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #444;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.progress-btn:hover {
  color: #555;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 9px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-goals">

  <h3 class="no-goal">$0</h3>
  <h3 class="first-goal">$1,000</h3>
  <h3 class="second-goal">$10,000</h3>
  <h3 class="last-goal">$100,000</h3>

</div>

<div class="progress-bg" id="progress-bg">

  <div class="goal-bar"></div>
  <div class="goal-bar"></div>
  <div class="goal-bar"></div>
  <div class="goal-bar"></div>

  <div class="progress-bar" id="progress-bar">
  </div>

</div>

<div class="progress-btn-container">
  <button class="progress-btn" onclick="move()">total donated</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this would be specifying an attribute on the progress bar itself. You could do something like `<div class="progress-bar" id="progress-bar" goal="20">`, where you add the attribute "goal" directly into the HTML.

Then, you can use the `getAttribute()` function to retrieve the value of it in your if statement, like `if (stepValue >= parseInt(elem.getAttribute("goal")) {...`, where you retrieve the attribute value, and parse it (which is a string value) into an integer for it to be properly compared with the stepValue.

Code:

```
function move() {
  let elem = document.getElementById("progress-bar");
  let stepValue = 0;
  let id = setInterval(frame, 50);

  function frame() {
    if (stepValue >= elem.getAttribute("goal")) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      elem.style.width = stepValue + 1 + "%";
      elem.innerHTML = stepValue + 1 + "%";
      stepValue = stepValue + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

```
body {
  max-width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
}

.progress-goals {
  margin: 20px auto 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.progress-goals h3 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.progress-goals:last-child {
  flex: 1;
}

.progress-bg {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0px auto 0px;
  height: 78px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #ccc;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #ccc;
}

.goal-bar {
  background-color: rgb(58, 58, 58);
  width: 5px;
  height: 78px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.progress-bar {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  background: linear-gradient( to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 18%, rgba(28, 53, 120, 0.8), rgba(220, 24, 27, 0.8));
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  transition: all 700ms ease;
}

.progress-btn-container {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 50px;
}

.progress-btn {
  /* display: block; */
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #444;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.progress-btn:hover {
  color: #555;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 9px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
}
```

```
<div class="progress-goals">

  <h3 class="no-goal">$0</h3>
  <h3 class="first-goal">$1,000</h3>
  <h3 class="second-goal">$10,000</h3>
  <h3 class="last-goal">$100,000</h3>

</div>

<div class="progress-bg" id="progress-bg">

  <div class="goal-bar"></div>
  <div class="goal-bar"></div>
  <div class="goal-bar"></div>
  <div class="goal-bar"></div>

  <div class="progress-bar" id="progress-bar" goal="20">
  </div>

</div>

<div class="progress-btn-container">
  <button class="progress-btn" onclick="move()">total donated</button>
</div>
```

Note that you'd have to figure out the percentage you want. $20,000 would probably be around 80%, so you'd put 80 in the goal attribute.

Comment: I have tried but seems doesn't work, can you make this example using code snippet? thank you

Comment: Now the bar is working, thanks. But what if I want, as I stated in the title of the post, the bar to show the amount (for example if I set '80' to the goal attribute to let bar arrive at its 80%, how can I let the bar shows on it "$20,000"?